# Unable to click on a radio button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, bots

I'm trying to click on a radio button with Selenium. It's button in the middle.
[image]

I'm not sure how to press the button, because all the attributes from this element are inside the input tags(shown in the picture) and that is not "on" the button.
If you inspect the button itself `<span class="checkmark"></span>` is marked.

I tried finding the button element by using Xpath.

```
cc_checkb = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id = 'payment_anycreditcard']/span[@class = 'checkmark']"))).click()
```

Also several other combinations didn't work.
Just using the `span[@class = 'checkmark']` didn't work as well, because the two other buttons are build with the same "span tag".

Comment: Testing for ALDI as a student worker?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking on the `label` element, XPath:

```
//label[@for='payment_anycreditcard']
```

Comment: Do you mind helping me out again? There is another radio button, but this time the only difference from the other button is the value. `<label class="container">
           <input type="radio" name="dynvalue[anykktype]" value="V" class="custom-control-input">
           <img src="https://www.sued.aldi-liefert.de/out/aldi/img/logo_visa.svg" class="logo-     payment" alt=""> VISA
           <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>` The code format is a little bit messed up

Comment: In case there will be another question and I will know the answer - sure

Comment: So there is Visa and Mastercard. Both container are identical, except for the value. Visa has 'V' and Mastercard 'M'. I tried for example `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type= 'radio'][@value='V']")))`

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question for this? If possible add there the link to the web page or at least a block of relevant HTML

Comment: I did it. Posted some of the source code as picture, because a link isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

```
//b[text()='Kreditkarte']//following-sibling::div/input[@id ='payment_anycreditcard]
```

replace your xpath to click on Kreditkarte radio button